# Пунктирное подчеркивание у элементов на странице вместо обычного

Tags: html, css

Что нужно сделать, чтобы у всех `<u></u>` на странице было пунктирное подчеркивание?

Comment: вопрос недели

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В CSS пишем:

```
u {
   border-bottom: 1px dashed #000080; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text-decoration:underline;
```